# Using google adsense with other ad providers

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

What are the legalities of using Google adsense alongside other providers like Viglink? Vigilink provides ads for external links. E.g. If I am reviewing a product I can put affiliate links on that product and get commission on sales. Does google allow this? I have read their agreement but I am not 100% sure that I understand whether it is or not allowed.

**EDIT** 
I keep reading on many websites/blogs etc though that Viglink usage might conflict with Google's Adsense terms. yet no one explains which. Does anyone know? Has anyone used them together? And in what way, thus not violating Google's terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Many of the Advertisements Programs are supported by Google. You can use Google Adsense and others simultaneously. Infolinks, Flpkart are examples.
But, if there is no compatibility it should be specifically mentioned it in the advertisement provider.Choose wisely.

Comment: Edited with more detail